# Service or way to input a table of lat long and return an output of street addresses?

Tags: software-recommendations, latitude-longitude, table, map-service, address

The following website can be used to enter a single pair of latitude and longitude coordinates and return a street address:

https://www.latlong.net/Show-Latitude-Longitude.html

I want to get street addresses for a table of lat long coords. Any ideas?

Comment: FYI, the site you link to is doing a process called "geocoding". What you want to do is "reverse geocoding". If you search on those two terms you'll probably find what you need.

Comment: Do you have a table in database ?

Comment: I created an excel table of lat long coords that I uploaded to Google Maps, then I downloaded that map as a KML. Now I have a feature class of points.

Answer (score 2):

You can use GeoPy to run a **reverse geocode** against a geocoding service, such as Google: https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

To find the address corresponding to a set of coordinates:

```
>>> from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
>>> geolocator = Nominatim()
>>> location = geolocator.reverse("52.509669, 13.376294")
>>> print(location.address)
Potsdamer Platz, Mitte, Berlin, 10117, Deutschland, European Union
>>> print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
(52.5094982, 13.3765983)
>>> print(location.raw)
{'place_id': '654513', 'osm_type': 'node', ...}
```

http://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html?highlight=reverse

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Python script or any other language, that will read list of latitutde and longitude from the table and then pass to the url, that is returning the response. First you will need to have the URL, you can get that from the Network in console.

Once you have the URL, you can write a Python script using "Request" and "BeautifulSoup", that will make call to the URL and return a response and then you can use that response.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a service to do that. It is called reverse geocoding and there are a few providers out there who can do that for you. The ones that are completely free will have some location offset from the actual target that can be from 50 miles to 1000 feet. [An example](https://www.openstreetmap.org/search?query=99%20monroe%20Ave%20Grand%20Rapids%20#map=17/43.70074/-85.48999) of such a service is OpenStreetMap. If you follow the OSM link for an address 99 Monroe Ave Grand Rapids you will get an offset of 60 miles. And if you put 99 Monroe Ave Grand Rapids MI USA you get address not found.

[image]

Our company also has a [batch reverse geocoding](https://csv2geo.com) service that we provide to users online. Our output places each address component separately as well as  we combine the full address in a separate column. You can read more about [reverse geocoding here](https://csv2geo.com/reversegeocoding)
For example, if you place these coordinates 42.9650099, -85.6732398 inside the text filed on the batch geocoding tool

[image]

and you click Go,then select reverse geocoding and process the data.

[image]

The resulting file will contain your original input plus each address token in a separate column, the combined address, the relevance to the address input (1.0 is best) and the distance offset from the actual target.

[image]

Disclosure: I am the founder of CSV2GEO